# Error in ReactiveCocoa after installation

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I installed ReactiveCocoa(5.0.4) to my project, but when I build it there is an error in ReactiveCocoa

[image: error]

xcode 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Which Swift Version are you using?

According to [the release notes](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases), RAC [5.0.4](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.4) supports Swift 3.1, whie RAC [5.0.3](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.3) supports Swift 3.0 and Swift 3.1.

If you're still using Swift 2.x, you'll likely need to use RAC [4.2.2](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/v4.2.2) instead of 5.x